# categorize by groupby-SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called list_details

```
listId     tier
1           5
1           5   
1           6   
2           4
2           5
```

I want the following result:

```
listId      tier    
1           5(2), 6(1)
2           4(1),5(1)
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT ld.listId,count(ld.tier)
from list_details ld
group by ld.listId
```

and it gives me :

```
listId      tier    
1           3
2           2
```

But I dont know how I can put the condition or... to categorize based on the tiers.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks Mike:

Your query result is:

```
ListId      tierData
1            5(2), 6(1), 4(1),5(1)

But I want:

listId      tier    
1           5(2), 6(1)
2           4(1),5(1)
```

Comment: Is this for `mysql` or `sql-server`? It can't be both, and the answers to get your desired output will require knowing which one it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you don;t really need the response in the format of `5(2), 6(1)` or if you did need that format for display, you could provide that format in teh application layer.

You should simply add multiple groupings:

```
SELECT
   listId,
   tier,
   COUNT(1) AS `tierCount`
FROM list_details
GROUP BY listId, tier
ORDER BY listId ASC, tier ASC
```

If you need that EXACT text result, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.listID AS listID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            a.tier,
            '(',
            a.tierCount,
            ')'
        )
    ) AS tierData
FROM (
    SELECT
       listId,
       tier,
       COUNT(1) AS `tierCount`
    FROM list_details
    GROUP BY listId, tier
) AS a
GROUP BY listID
ORDER BY listID ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! But I'm pretty sure there is a way to get the exact result; I used to use it! Although it is not common!

Comment: @user3000457 Yes you can get that exact result, check out updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ld.listId, ld.tier, count(ld.tier) 
FROM list_details ld 
GROUP by ld.listId, ld.tier;
```

Will yield:

```
list_id tier count
1  5  2
1  6  1
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You want to `GROUP BY` both `listid` and `tier`.

```
SELECT 
    ld.listId,
    ld.tier,
    count(ld.tier)
FROM list_details ld
GROUP BY ld.listId, ld.tier
```

This will result in:

```
listId    tier    count
1         5       2
1         6       1
2         4       1
2         5       1
```

That isn't your desired output 100%, but it's close. To get your desired output will require some funky SQL, or to display the result like that in your UI.